# Oracle SQL database

Tags: sql

How to create a timestamp record that having the AM/PM period separately?

By using the following code:

```
create table wz(day_ timestamp);
insert into wz(day_)
values('16/may/12 5.56.35.');
select *from wz;
```

I get the following output:

```
16-MAY-12 05.56.35.000000 AM
```

Like this, how do I create for PM?

Answer (score 0):

for Oracle

```
insert into wz(day_) values('16/may/12 5.56.35.');
insert into wz(day_) values('16/may/12 15.56.35');
insert into wz(day_) values('16/may/12 23.56.35');
insert into wz(day_) values('16/may/12 0.0.0');
insert into wz(day_) values('16/may/12 12.0.0');

select to_char(day_,'dd/Mon/yyyy hh12.mi.ss AM')from wz;
```